# jQuery to get result of value enter from DB using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am working on a project like remitano where you can enter Amount you need  and the system will show list of members that have up to that amount.
I don't know where to start the jQuery code and connect it to my controller.

I have try this code and I don't know where to end it

```
<input type="number" class="form-control checks" name="amount" value="">
<div id="nots"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
// Ajax post
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checks').change(function(){
        var amount = $('.checks').val();
        $('#nots').html('<span class="label label-danger btn-lg"> amount is '+amount+'</span>');
    });
});
```

Kindly see [this link](https://remitano.com/ng/quick/sell-bitcoin) for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller have a function like this:

```
public function getmembers($amount = null) {
    if (is_numeric($amount) && $amount > 0) {
        // Get matching members from your model
        $members = $this->member_model->getMembersByAmount($amount);
        echo json_encode($members);
    }
}
```

In your model you would have a function `getMembersByAmount()` which fetches a list from your database of all members with that amount of greater.

Then your jQuery could be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checks').on("change", function(){
        var amount = $('#checks').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.yourdomain.com/member/getmembers/" + amount,
            success: function(data) {
                // Do something with the json data returned from CodeIgniter
                // I like to use https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender for templating at this point
            }
        });
    }
});
```